# Nightwatch Internet Explorer - argument for private mode

Tags: node.js, selenium, internet-explorer, incognito-mode, nightwatch

In my `nightwatch.conf.js` I have:

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "internet explorer",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
            },
```

What is the name of the property that will run IE in Private mode?

The only answer I could find is this:

```
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);  
    сapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
```

-- but I don't know how to add that to the JSON config.

I've tried:

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "internet explorer",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "IE_SWITCHES": "private",
            },
```

and:

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "internet explorer",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "args": "private",
            },
```

Without luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **forceCreateProcessApi** and **browserCommandLineSwitches** capabilities.

Try to set the forceCreateProcessApi to **True**  and set the browserCommandLineSwitches as "**-private**"

More detail information, please check the following links:

[Internet Explorer Setup](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Internet-Explorer-Setup)

[IE-specific DesiredCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#ie-specific)